# !heap -s not showing growing heaps in windbg

Tags: windows, winapi, memory-leaks, windbg

I have written an application that is leaking memory - I've done the following in the past

1. find the heap that's leaking with
   **!heap -s**
2. inspect the heap with
   **!heap -stat -h**
3. see the callstack for the allocation with
   **!heap -p -a**

to get the callstacks I add +ust to gflags

while I've done this in the past with great success, !heap -s isnt showing any growth today? I have no idea whats wrong?

it's like my allocations are in a heap hidden from !heap -s?

ideas?  I'm compiling (both x86 and x64) using Visual Studio 2010 pro.  Using windbg to debug

Comment: FWIW: I modified my program to leak a ton of memory - taskmgr shows the memory usage going WAY up but !heap -s does not

Comment: this is on a 64 bit machine, with 64 bit leaking app, windbg, and gflags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the punchline - when allocations are <1MB (default) they go to HeapAlloc(),  when they're bigger than 1MB they go to VirtualAlloc instead

VirtualAlloc doesnt appear with !heap -s

Comment: how are you allocating? Your own custom allocator?